# Como obtengo los dias, horas minutos y segundo de una resta de fechas en excel?

Tags: excel

La idea es que al restar una fecha, esta me muestre el resultado en dias, horas, minutos y segundos

Por ejemplo, quiero que me indique que la diferencia entre **30-04-2020 0:00:00** y **AHORA()** que seria por ejemplo: **16-03-2020 11:37:54** es igual a 44 dias, 12 horas, 22 minutos y 06 segundos

Answer (score 1):

Te planteo la siguiente solución para hacerlo de forma fácil... Lo primero es configurar las celdas que contienen las fechas a comparar con el formato **dd/mm/yyy h:mm**

Para este caso, la fórmula es **=C3-B3** en las celdas **D3** y **E3**

A la celda que muestra la cantidad de días, le pones formato **Número** y a la de horas, minutos y segundos, le pones formato **Hora**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]